# MKMapView regionWillChangeAnimated Zoom or Pan?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I need to know whether a regionWillChangeAnimated occurred due to zooming or panning.

I was able to figure this out for regionDidChangeAnimated by keeping track of the old region span and comparing with the new one to see if a zoom occurred.

The problem with regionWillChangeAnimated is that it is called before the region changes so I have no way to know what the region span will be.

Is there another way perhaps to figure this out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compare the current span of the map with the previous one in `mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:`, which gets called many times during zooming or scrolling.

You can use code from the [breadcrumb sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Breadcrumb/Listings/Breadcrumb_BreadcrumbViewController_m.html): `MKZoomScale currentZoomScale = (CGFloat)(map.bounds.size.width / map.visibleMapRect.size.width);`

Answer (score 1):

i believe you will need to get the current region span and center data in the regionWillChangeAnimated call and compare it once you get to the regionDidChangeAnimated call but dont do too much logic in there or it can make the user interaction choppy.

Comment: Yeah the problem is I need to know whether a zoom occurs *while* the map is being zoomed and not only *after* its been zoomed so I can't rely on regionDidChangeAnimated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation quota to comment, but felt the need to warn anyway: you can't use just the region span of the map to determine if a zoom has occurred. For a constant zoom level, the horizontal scale of the map varies based on latitude.